# django ForeignKey get to_field

Tags: django, django-models

If I make a ForeignKey definition in a model that has a to_field column definition is it possible to get that to_field value later?

```
class author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    customId=models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, unique=True)

class book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author=models.ForeignKey(author,to_field='customId')
```

As shown above the foreignkey to author uses the `to_field` key, later on in my code I have to deal with book objects but would like to find out what field the author is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, your `ForeignKey` field will be defined by adding `_id` into it. So you can just access that `to_field` directly.

```
book.author_id == book.author.customId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_field to get `to_field` value

```
>>> book._meta.get_field('author').foreign_related_fields
(<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: customId>,)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `to_field` is not necessary, just use `author.customId` to refer the value.